# Inflating Custom View into Layout

Tags: android, layout, viewgroup, android-inflate

I am trying to inflate a custom view object into my Layout XML, but I am getting an inflate exception, can someone help me?

Here is my Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/desenha_foto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_capture"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="snapIt" 
    android:text="@string/Capture"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code, where I try to inflate the ViewGroup:

```
public class Desenha_Foto extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DesenhaFotoView draw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bitmap bitmap = Global.getInstance().getBitmap();
        draw = new DesenhaFotoView(this, bitmap);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_desenha_foto);

        final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.desenha_foto);
        viewGroup.addView(draw);

        Global.getInstance().getProgressDialog().dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or I don't see the inflate statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `ViewGroup` tag in the xml layout because `ViewGroup` is an abstract class. You either use one of `ViewGroup`'s children(`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc) or you use a custom implementation(a class that extends `ViewGroup`). You have your own view, `DesenhaFotoView` use that instead of the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I edited the XML and now I am using com.iscte.dcti.daam.letters4kids_test.DesenhaFotoView instead of ViewGroup, but how can I attach my custom view object to it ? the draw object ? because the object itself has the bitmap..

Comment: @DarkLink You don't attach the `View` again, if you declared the view in the layout instead of the `ViewGroup` it should be visible unless the implementation is faulty. After adding the view you don't see it? Did you tried using the custom view in a simple layout to see if it's showing(or if it's properly showing)?

Comment: look you are not understanding. In the code I have this new DesenhaFotoView(this, bitmap);  , but now using my custom view on the layout XML I dont have access to this object, how can I pass the bitmap as argument ?

Comment: @DarkLink I didn't see that. If your custom view has that constructor you can't use it in the layout. You have several choices: you could very simple replace the `ViewGroup` from the xml with a `FrameLayout`, in the `onCreate()` method you would then use the exact same code. Or you could add the custom view directly to the root `RelativeLayout`(by searching for it and using the proper `LayoutParams`).

Comment: I used a Global variable using the Global instance.. it worked. Thanks alot in advance. I have now my Custom View and Spinner on the bottom, but the spinner has the custom view as background, why ? the custom view is using the entire screen.

Comment: @DarkLink Check the way you arranged the views in the layout and remember that layouts like `FramneLayout` and `RelativeLayout` stack their children by default(so each one gets on top of others if they don't have the proper rules).